# How to set Row & Column in shell Script

Tags: shell, shell-script, columns

I just made my first shell script with the help of others, and it works as expected, but I want to organize it more.

The current script:

```
{ date '+%F %T';
    "$ipath"/cli iedge list |
       awk 'BEGIN { print "Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"}
           /Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
           /Ongoing Calls/ { print id,$3 }'
} >> "$ifile"
```

Its output:

```
- Registration ID Ongoing Calls
  - Nitin_03 30
  - Nitin_01 0
```

Instead I want the output formatted as follows:

```
-------------------------------------
|Registration ID   |  Ongoing Calls |
-------------------------------------
| Nitin_03         |     30         |
-------------------------------------
| Nitin_01         |      0         |
-------------------------------------
```

How would I go about doing that? I tried the following and it mostly works, but when I added another "character" I got a fatal error.

```
ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
ifile=/root/Nick.csv
"$ipath"/cli igrp list | awk '
  BEGIN { print "------------------------------------";
  printf "|%-17s|%-16s|%-15s|\n","Iedge Group", "maxCallsIn"   
  "maxCallsOut"
  }
  /Iedge Group/ { id = $3; next }
  /maxCallsIn/
  /maxCallsOut/{print "------------------------------------"; printf    
   "|%-17s|%-16s|%-15s\n",id,$3 } 
   END{
   print "------------------------------------";
   }'
```

I started getting this error when I added `maxCallsOut`:

```
awk: cmd. line:3: fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `|%-17s|%-16s|%-15s|
'
                         ^ ran out for this one
```

Comment: You did not get that code from me.  I did not, for example, use `printf id,$3`.  The corresponding equation in my code is `printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\n",id,$3` which is very different.    Please check my answer again.

Comment: @john1024 i am sorry you are correct, i was trying incorrect manner what you suggested that is why it was coming in invalid format.

Comment: `printf "|%-17s|%-16s|%-15s\n",id,$3`  The reason for the error is that you added a third format string but did not add a third variable.  The number of format strings and the number of variables need to match.

Answer (score 1):

To get formatted output from awk, use `printf`:

```
$ "$ipath"/cli iedge list | awk 'BEGIN { print "------------------------------------"; printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\n","Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"} /Registration ID/ { id = $3; next } /Ongoing Calls/ {print "------------------------------------"; printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\n",id,$3 } END{print "------------------------------------";}'
------------------------------------
|Registration ID  |Ongoing Calls   |
------------------------------------
|Nitin_03         |30              |
------------------------------------
|Nitin_01         |0               |
------------------------------------
```

If it is easier to read, the following is the same but spread over several lines in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
"$ipath"/cli iedge list | awk '
BEGIN { print "------------------------------------";
        printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\n","Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"
      }
/Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
/Ongoing Calls/ {print "------------------------------------"; printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\n",id,$3 }
END{
    print "------------------------------------";
   }
'
```

The `printf` statements can be adjusted to get whatever format you prefer.

Comment: i tried printf it is not wrking and even it is giving very bad output.. I updated in question..you can see now